# How to get native points on a elliptic curve from an existing addition of points

Tags: python, cryptography, sage, elliptic-curve

I'm working on elliptic curves with SageMath.
I know :

1. The equation of the curve E defined by y^2 = x^3 + ... : `E = EllipticCurve( GF(K), [m, n] )`
2. the addition of points A and B (A+B) : `(x3;y3)`
3. the substraction of points A and B (A-B) : `(x4;y4)`

Here my goal is to find **both A `(x1;y1)` and B `(x2;y2)`**.
I obviously understand how to find (A+B) but don't find how to reverse it and get A and B from the addition of A and B and the substraction too.

I know too I can use these kind of function to generate (A+B) coordinates from A and B coordinates. Here I use the slope of the native elliptic curve given by : `-x1 -x2 + (y1-y2)^2/(x1-x2)^2`.

```
    E = EllipticCurve( GF(K), [m, n] )
    # We know A and B coords
    def x3(A, B):
        x1, y1 = A.xy()
        x2, y2 = B.xy()
        return -x1 -x2 + (y1-y2)^2/(x1-x2)^2
    x3(A, B)
```

I guess there should be something to do with it but I really don't see how to begin.

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks !

**EDIT :**

Having C=A+B and D=A-B, I made a try with C+D :

```
C = E(x3, y3)
D = E(x4, y4)
Z = C + D
# Z gives : Z(x5, y5)
```

I get new coordinates `Z(x5, y5)` but I could not find both A and B coordinates, which does not fit to what I'd like to do.

Comment: You have C=A+B and D=A-B. What happens if you compute C+D?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to compute C + D and get new coordinates `Z(x5, y5)` . But I could not find both A and B coordinates.

Comment: Yes, and Z = C + D = A+B+A-B = 2A. So can you find the value of A if you have the value of 2A? How big is K here?

Comment: The size of K is : 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951 (this is a secp256r1 elliptic curve)

Comment: Ok when I try 2A/2 on sagemaths it fails ```(unsupported operand parent(s) for /)```.  Should I do something like (A + B) - A to find B coords after ?

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953558/is-there-an-efficient-formula-for-computing-point-halving-on-elliptic-curves-in) for more discussion.